# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: con.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to access a `MySql` database through servlet but it shows

```
      java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: con.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

and

```
      java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aptitude
```

I am using `xampp` for implementation of program, and I already set the classpath of `mysql` connector,and also put the `mysql-connector` to `web-inf\lib` but I m still facing the same problem.

Suggestions?

```
        import java.sql.*;
        import java.io.*;
        import javax.servlet.*; 
        import javax.servlet.http.*;
         public class aptservlet1 extends HttpServlet
         {
          public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException,  ServletException
           {
           String correct=2+"";
           res.setContentType("text/html");
           PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
           String user,pass;
          user=req.getParameter("user");
          pass=req.getParameter("pass");
         //apt1 o1=new apt1();
          user=user.trim();
          pass=pass.trim();


          try
            {
            Class.forName("con.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ce)
           {
           out.println(ce+"<br>");
             }


            try
             {

            String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + "aptitude";
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
            Statement s=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("select a_pass from admin_database where                    a_user='"+user+"'");
            rs.next();
            String s1=rs.getString(1);

            if(s1.equals(pass))
                {
                correct=1+"";
                 }
            else
               {
               correct=0+"";
                }
              rs.close();
               s.close();
              con.close();
               }
              catch(SQLException se)
                  {
                  out.println(se+"<br>");
                 }

              out.println("value of correct="+correct);
              ServletContext sc=this.getServletContext();
              } 
               }
```

Comment: You misspelled the driver name. It should be "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelled the class wrong, you said CON.myspl.jdbc.Driver instead of com.mysql.jdbc.Driver